# how to loop through two array in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get my data from 2 arrays:

Here is my function:

```
function Cart({ basketProps }) {
  let productsInCart = [];

  Object.keys(basketProps.products).forEach(function (item) {
    if (basketProps.inCart) {
      productsInCart.push(basketProps.products);
    }
    console.log(productsInCart);
  });

  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

when i do console.log it return me this:

```
[{…}]
0:
products: Array(1)
0:
img_url1: "https://thebeuter.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/38-1.jpg"
price: 1290000
title: "BEUTER BACK2BACK ZIPPER WHITE JACKET"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

How can I use .map to loop thru these?

Updated:
When I do console.log(basketProps). It gave me this:

```
basketNumbers: 1
cartCost: 1290000
inCart: true
numbers: 1
products:
 products: Array(1)
  0: {title: "BEUTER BACK2BACK ZIPPER WHITE JACKET", price: 1290...}
```

Comment: you have item as an argument for the function but you are using basketProps within the function. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Yes. Here is my github project if you want to look up my code: https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

Answer (score 1):

To select all products `inCart` use:

1. [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select all products `inCart`
2. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (or `flatMap`) to select `products` property you're interested in

I use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) because it makes list easier to render - it makes an array of products, not an array of product arrays. `flatMap` first maps each element using a mapping function, then flattens the result into a new array (it is identical to a map() followed by a flat() of depth 1).

```js
function App() {
  return <Cart basketProps={DATA} />;
}

function Cart({ basketProps }) {
  const productsInCart = basketProps
    .filter(product => product.inCart)
    .flatMap(product => product.products);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {productsInCart.map(product => (
          <li>{product.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const DATA = [
  { inCart: true, products: [
    { title: "PRODUCT 1", price: 10 },
    { title: "PRODUCT 2", price: 20 }
  ]},
  { inCart: false, products: [
    { title: "PRODUCT 3", price: 30 },
    { title: "PRODUCT 4", price: 40 }
  ]},
  { inCart: true, products: [
    { title: "PRODUCT 5", price: 50 },
    { title: "PRODUCT 6", price: 60 }
  ]}
];

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont require the 'Object.keys' function, since inCart is already available at outer level.

```
if (basketProps.inCart) {
  productsInCart.push(basketProps.products);
}
let total =0;

productsInCart.map(cartProduct=>{
 total = total + cartProduct.price;
}
```

You can run the map function on productInCart array like above.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `basketProps.products` is an object array which has list of products, and has `inCart = true` if the product is in cart

In that case your code to get the products in cart should be like this

```
let productsInCart = [];

 if(basketProps && Array.isArray(basketProps.products)) {
    productsInCart = basketProps.products.filter(function (item) {
       return item.inCart ;    
   });
}
console.log(productsInCart )
```

or if you are using arrow functions, the one liner would be (add array validation as in example above)

```
let productsInCart = basketProps.products.filter((item)=>(item.inCart));
console.log(productsInCart);
```

Comment: im getting: TypeError: basketProps.products.filter is not a function

Comment: Is `basketProps.products` an array? If you we may need to check if data is available. I will update answser